# eclipse visual editor

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded eclipse 3.7 but I don't know how to download visual editor! I need to make a GUI. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of eclipse 3.7 did you download?

If you download the  **Java Developers version** , a brand new GUI editor called **WindowBuilder** is already included in it . Go to this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigor) to download eclipse 3.7 Java Developers version. Then refer [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/index.html) for the User Guide , and [this](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html) for the Quick Start guide

If you want to install it as a plugin , you can refer [this](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) for the link and installation instructions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target Swing, you can use [Google's WindowBuilder](https://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html).

Comment: @SunyGirl: I'm sorry, I was assuming you were saying a GUI editor in general, not a specific plugin. The plugin named Visual Editor [seems to be archived](http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/archives/ve.tgz).